# How do I use bmesh on a set?

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

I have an array that is called `ccValids`, which contains "good" center coordinates for the cylinders I want to create. These cylinders are created as follows:

```
for c in ccValids:
    leafs = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add( location = c, enter_editmode = True )

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(leafs)
```

It appears that the cylinders are created as one object, which is very good since there is a great number of them and they are all supposed to be manipulated by the exact same operations. However the `bmesh.new()` command does not work.

The error I get is "Expected 'Mesh' found 'set' instead". Is there a way to use bmesh methods on my nicely gathered cylinders though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly the issue and error with your code.

Operators only return a python  **set** containing the status of the operation, for example `{'FINISHED'}` if finished normally, or `{'CANCELLED'}` if there was a problem.

On looping a primitive add operator, the object will be `context.object` the mesh `context.object.data` on each iteration.  If run in edit mode, (`enter_editmode` takes you into edit mode on first iteration) then all will be added to the edit objects mesh. This is why you have one object.

Secondly, I'd probably use the [bmesh create cone operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.create_cone) as pointed out in [answer by @TLousky](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91682/15543),  for completeness here is a way to put the created cylinders into a "live" bmesh, that is a [bmesh from the edit objects edit mesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html#bmesh.from_edit_mesh).  To demonstrate, I've put in code to select the ngon caps of the cylinders.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context
ccValids = [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
for c in ccValids:
    leafs = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add( location = c, enter_editmode = True )
# we will now be in edit mode
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(context.edit_object.data)
# deselect all but ngon faces
for f in bm.faces:
    f.select = len(f.verts) > 4
```

[image]
*Result.  Still in edit  mode, cylinder ngon caps selected.*

When you've finished operations, a [`bmesh.update_edit_mesh(context.object.data)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html#bmesh.update_edit_mesh) will update the edit mesh.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create cylinders with [bmesh's create cone operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.create_cone), then create a mesh, an object and link the object to the scene:

```
import bpy, bmesh

# Imports used to demo code since I don't really have ccValids
from random import randint
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix

# Generate 5 random centers for our cylinders
ccValids = [ Vector([ randint(-5,5) for axis in 'xyz' ]) for i in range(5) ]

bm = bmesh.new()
for c in ccValids:
    # Create a cylinder using the create_cone operator with an identical top and bottom diameter
    m = Matrix()
    bmesh.ops.create_cone( 
        bm, 
        diameter1 = 1, 
        diameter2 = 1, 
        depth     = 3, 
        segments  = 12,
        matrix    = m.Translation( c )
    )

# Create a mesh and object to represent our bmesh data in the scene
m = bpy.data.meshes.new('cyl')
bm.to_mesh( m )
o = bpy.data.objects.new('cyl', m )
bpy.context.scene.objects.link( o )
```

The Create cone operator takes various parameters and can control whether the cone / cylinder has caps, uses triangles or quads and other stuff in addition to the obvious parameters of diameter and depth.

```
create_cone()
BMeshOpFunc bmesh.ops.create_cone(bmesh, cap_ends=False, cap_tris=False, segments=0, diameter1=0.0, diameter2=0.0, depth=0.0, matrix=Matrix(), calc_uvs=False)
-> dict(verts=[])
```

Comment: I looked up what create_cone does, but I don't get the matrix-parameter. It says "matrix to multiply the new geometry with", what does this mean? Why is it not just a vector that denotes the origin?

Comment: @Gnub, this is the entire Transformation matrix of the new object, which controls translation, rotation and scale all at once. I only set the translation as shown above, but you can also use `m.Rotation( r )` and provide an Euler or Quaternion, or set an `m.Scale( s )` with a scale vector.